# Euro truck simulator Music file

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I got the game from a friend and there's no music file for the game. I would like music but i don't know how to put it in without the file.

Comment: If you have no music, did you install the game properly?

Answer (score 5):

Custom music is loaded from `My Documents\Euro Truck Simulator 2\music` folder.

You can also add internet radio streams to the game by adding the stream URL to a config file. To do this:

1. Load ETS2 at least once, and navigate to Radio -> Streaming ->
   Update From Internet
2. Open My Documents\Euro Truck Simulator 2\live_streams.sii in Notepad
3. Scroll to the bottom of the list and add in new stations in the same
   format as the ones above
4. Make sure the stream numbers are unique for each line
   (stream_data[XX], where as XX are supposed to be unique
   sequential/following numbers for every station. i.e.
   1,2,3,4...,70,71,72)

[source](http://euro-truck-simulator-2.wikia.com/wiki/Radio_Stations)